# Remove ecto migration from the plan

Tags: elixir, ecto

I generated a migration by

```
mix ecto.gen.migration migration_name
```

I did not run the migration and decided not to run it at all.
I deleted the migration file from priv folder, however, it still appears in the migration plan. Is there any way how to delete such a migration?

Comment: What's a migration plan?

Comment: @JustMichael it is a list i see when write down mix ecto.migrations (the mentioned migration is still there with status: down)

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I think if you delete the file, it will be just fine, it won't be run. Not sure how to handle the migration plan or if it's actually important.

Comment: Are you sure the file has been deleted? I just created a migration, it showed up in `mix ecto.migrations`, then I deleted it and I don't see it in `mix ecto.migrations`.

Comment: @MirekSurma, If you have deleted migration file from repo/migrations then It wont appear in migrations list. So check whether that file is deleted or not.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. The problem was that file was deleted from sources but still existed in the build dir.

Answer (score 2):

If you execute a migration (upwards), ecto will create a new entry in the `schema_migrations` table of your database.

The entry for the missing file is probably still there.